# Javascript Help Passing Data via URL

Tags: javascript, url, get

Hi I wonder if someone could help me with this small issue I have the following code which I need to modify.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function code(id) {
  $('#myStyle').load('myphp.php?id=' + id);
}
</script>
```

I need to pass another variable into this code and add it to the GET part of the URL for example above it will include the URL myphp.php?id=124545

I want to add a second variable called num to the URL part but am confused what the code will need to become to make the correct post via GET

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function code(id,num) {
  $('#myStyle').load('myphp.php?id=' + id); // how do I add the &num=124 for example
} 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basic string concatenation....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Use:
`$('#myStyle').load('myphp.php?id=' + id + '&num=' + num);`

Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc

Hope it helps!

Comment: If **this or any other answers** helped you here, feel free to pick an "accepted" answer by clicking a check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate `"&num="+num` onto the string you already have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function code(id,num) {
  $('#myStyle').load('myphp.php?id=' + id  + "&num=" + num); // how do I add the &num=124 for example
} 
</script>
```